# PHP serialize/unserialize like method in Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, serialization

I have serialized a string in PHP using serialize method

```
$serializedResult = serialize($value);
```

How to unserialize this serialized string in Objective-C

Comment: Do you have to use that format? Cannot you use something more cross-platform, like JSON?

Comment: @Thilo, i have used json encoding before serialization. the fact that, array => serialization => encryption => json_encode, at first i got result from database, then i serialized the result prior to encryption, then i have encoded the result through json. now what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a serialized PHP object parser for Objective C.

However you could use JSON instead. On the PHP side use `json_encode`, and on the Objective C side see: http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Or as Tommy pointed out the now native implementation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That blog post is pre-iOS 5; you'd just use Apple's own built-in `NSJSONSerialization +JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` nowadays.

Comment: @Petah i found serialize response from PHP like
**a:4{i:0;s:6:"Vincent";i:1;s:14:"Julie";i:2;s:12:"Tomas";i:3;s:10:"John";}** 
at that time SBJSON and NSJSONSerialization gives error for starting character. Have you any idea for such un-serialization ?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem occur to me. As solution i wrote parser to do this job. It have both serialization and deserialization functions.You can get it from this [link](https://github.com/hasinthajanaka/Objective-C-php-Serializer.m).

This is the testing example for serialization,
RTSerializer *serializer=[[RTSerializer alloc]init];

```
  NSMutableDictionary *pack=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [pack setValue:@"id" forKey:@"3"];
  [pack setValue:@"tariffid" forKey:@"152"];
  [pack setValue:@"rgid" forKey:@"1"];
  [pack setValue:@"name" forKey:@"Test"];


   NSString *_data=@"";
   _data=[serializer pack inString:_data];
```

example for desrialization,

```
 id object=[serializer deserialize:@"a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"3\";s:8:\"tariffid\";s:3:\"152\";s:4:\"rgid\";s:1:\"1\";s:4:\"name\";s:4:\"Test\";}}"];
```

Comment: It seems that your unserializer doesn't work properly.

Comment: However, your code is a good base. Just created a pull request with some edits that fix your RTSerializer ;) Now it works pretty well

Comment: Hi @Martin can you share the updated copy for helping others ?

Comment: Hello @BurhanMughal, I sent a PR to the owner, but he never answered. The edited code is on my repo : https://github.com/martinprot/Objective-C-php-Serializer.m /!\ not tested on new iOS versions since one year.

Comment: @BurhanMughal Is the github which is provided working for current iOS version.I want to try this code in swift.Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is possible. According to PHP manual serialize method is supposed to be used only inside PHP scripts.

You should use some open formats, like JSON. Or you can create your own "serialize" implementation in both languages.

Comment: i have used json encoding before serialization. the fact that, array => serialization => encryption => json_encode, at first i got result from database, then i serialized the result prior to encryption, then i have encoded the result through json. now what should i do?

Comment: The point is to use JSON instead of serialization, NOT with it.

Comment: Yes, JSON is better for this purpose