# How do i parse this a:2:{i:0;s:19:"Broker - Securities";i:1;s:18:"Financial Services";}

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

From a web service I am getting this output:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:19:"Broker - Securities";i:1;s:18:"Financial Services";}
```

I don't know which format this is. Is this JSON? Can anyone help me parse this in **objective c**?

From that I need to get the following values:

**Broker - Securities**

**Financial Services**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could remove the prefix and stay with { ..... } ,
then use 
    [yourstring stringByReplcaingOccurencesOfString:@";" withString:@","];
then remove the char in     string.length - 1 
then use the     JSONObjectWithData.

Answer (score 0):

It is PHP serialisation, and you can read it with PHP's function [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). The meaning is quite straightforward if you want to parse it yourself:

```
two-element array
  integer 0 =>
    19-char string "Broker - Securities"
  integer 1 =>
    18-char string "Financial Services"
```

Comment: Given the tags, this person probably wants to parse this data in an iOS app using Objective-C, not PHP.

Comment: @maddy: Probably. He's out of luck though, AFAIK (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136119/php-serialize-unserialize-like-method-in-objective-c), which is why I provided the semantics (so he can implement deserialisation himself).